# Is linear interpolation applicable here

Tags: functions, interpolation, variable-definitions

From my understanding about [Linear Interpolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_interpolation) especially of that of [Newton's Divided Difference Polynomial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton_polynomial), we could get the value of `F(x)` from the given set of coordinates.

But would it be possible of the if `x` values itself is an expression, like `0.25X` and having a constant value of `0.5`. I don't know if I get the correct  understanding of the NDDP: Linear Interpolation correctly given the scenario.

Given the set of coordinates. How would I find the value for `X = 0.4x` where `x = is integer constant to the plane`

```
X     Y
0     0.25
0.25x 0.5
0.5x  1
0.75x 2
x     4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See if this works for you, as I am not sure I understood the question well.

```
y[n_] /; n == 0 := 0.25;
y[n_] := 2*y[n - 1];
f[k_] := Table[{n*y[0] k, y[n]}, {n, 0, 5}]
constantToThePlane = 1;
data = f[constantToThePlane];
g = Interpolation[data];
p1 = Plot[g[x], {x, 0, data[[-1, 1]]}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}];
p2 = ListPlot[data, Mesh -> True, Filling -> Axis, 
     PlotStyle -> {Red, PointSize[0.015]}];
pt = {PointSize[.05], Point[{0.4 constantToThePlane, g[0.4 constantToThePlane]}]};
Show[p1, p2, Graphics[pt], Frame -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The plots plots the new point at 0.4 X, where X is your constantToThePlane. The actual value of 0.4*X is

```
 g[0.4 constantToThePlane]
 (*0.754*)
```

**Update:**

Here is an example of trying a quadratic polynomial:

```
y[n_] /; n == 0 := 0.25;
y[n_] := 2*y[n - 1];
f[k_] := Table[{n*y[0] k, y[n]}, {n, 0, 5}]
constantToThePlane = 1;
data = f[constantToThePlane];
p2 = ListPlot[data, Mesh -> True, Filling -> Axis, 
    PlotStyle -> {Red, PointSize[0.015]}];
guess1 = a + b x + c x^2;
guess1Data = FindFit[data, guess1, {a, b, c}, x]
Labeled[Show[Plot[guess1 /. guess1Data, {x, 0, data[[-1, 1]]}], p2, 
     Frame -> True, PlotRange -> All, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}], 
 Row[{"fitting to ", guess1 /. guess1Data}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Basing from the illustration, you got the right idea. Unfortunately, I can't read your solution properly. Sorry little bit of an rookie in your solution but what language did you use?

Comment: @Dr.Java you ask `what language did you use?`, I am using Mathematica, or now known as `Wolfram language`. This is a programming language made by company called Wolfram research. They have student version, and also personal version and commerical version. see http://www.wolfram.com/ to buy a copy from the online store there.

Comment: Thanks. For the mean time. Is there a direct equation/formula for the graph above?

Comment: The formula would be more delighted. I didn't know that Mathematica was a program tool, instead of a SE about Math - in which was Mathematics.